# map over complex javascript array of objects to get values

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, object

I have a big document that shows nutrition data of a dummy recipe.

**Look at the codesandbox json first**

i want to get total calories and nutrition facts of this object;

recipe has an array of stuffs and in stuffs array we have 2 item objectes;

each item has fact ( facts );

facts are ( vitamins, nutrition, calories and others )

each fact has value;

I tried many nested array.map high order function, for example i got calories of each item, but problem was that nested map function returns each calorie value in a seperate array...

i want to push values of each item(recipe stuff item) in arrays like this:

```
const vitaminValues = []
const nutritionValues = []
const caloriesValues = []
const othersValues = []
```

if i get this, i can get total calories, vitamins, nutrition and others information

but idk, if u guys have any better ideas just help me :) thanks

this is JSON file of sample recipe : https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-brown-zrxnr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: `flatMap` is your friend. I won't say more until you provide your earnest attempt

Comment: please mention what output you want from this

Comment: @SohanPatil, as I said, I want to calculate and get sum of calories, nutrition, vitamins and others of all and each stuff in a recipe

Comment: can you pleae provide sample output

Comment: @SohanPatil , I said

Comment: @SohanPatil `` const vitaminValues = [ //for example 24, 102, 342 ] `` same as nutrition, calories and others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let data=//your json
let vitaminValues = [];
let nutritionValues = [];
let caloriesValues = [];
let othersValues = [];
let vitaminAValues = [];

function getValuesFromJson(obj, Arr) {
  Object.entries(obj).map(
    vitamin => vitamin[1].hasOwnProperty("value") && Arr.push(vitamin[1].value)
  );
}
data.map(d =>
  d.stuffs.map(stuff =>
    stuff.item.fact.map(f => {
      getValuesFromJson(f.vitamins, vitaminValues);
      getValuesFromJson(f.others, othersValues);
      caloriesValues.push(f.calories);
      f.nutritions.map(nutri => getValuesFromJson(nutri, nutritionValues));
      vitaminAValues.push(f.vitamins.A.value);
    })
  )
);
console.log("vitaminValues", vitaminValues);
console.log("nutritionValues", nutritionValues);
console.log("othersValues", othersValues);
console.log("caloriesValues", caloriesValues);
console.log("vitaminAValues", vitaminAValues);
```

Comment: Thanks it works well! <3
What if i want all other childs?
for example :

Comment: vitaminA_values = []
vitaminC_values = []
vitaminD_values = []
vitaminB6_values = []

calcium_values = []
iron_values = []
cobalamin_values = []
magnesium_values = []

Comment: fat_values = []
cholesterol_values = []
sodium_values = []
potassium_values = []
carbohydrate_values = []
protein_values = []

Comment: @tafhim i have edited the code for adding values to `vitaminAValues` array you can repeat the same for other vitamins